# function descriptors in c

Tags: c

i'm trying to implement a simple array of function descriptors of type fun_desc

```
struct fun_desc {
  char *name;
  void (*fun)();
};
```

i have 2 function f1 and f2 both are of type coolFunct

```
typedef int (*coolFunct) (unsigned int);
```

my array is defined as follows

```
struct fun_desc funArr[]={{"f1", &f1}, {"f2",&f2}};
```

now i am trying to call a function in the array, i presume i need to cast it to coolFunct because it is of unspecified type (or am i wrong)
but the next call doesn't work (no compile or runtime error, just nothing happens) :

```
((coolFunct)(funArr[0].fun))(1);
```

as always help is greatly appreciated thanks ...

Comment: Is there a compelling reason not to do `struct fun_desc { char *name; int (*fun)(unsigned int); };` ?

Comment: or even use the typedef in the struct

Comment: Also, do these functions have visible side effects? Or are you/should you be collecting/displaying the return value?

Comment: Works for me with gcc 4.4 even without the cast. What C compiler are you using? Have you tried stepping with a debugger?

Comment: @Emil - The cast is necessary. It's UB without. Also, without the cast the `int` return value is impossible to collect.

Comment: What happens when you do `int i = ((coolFunct)funArr[0].fun)(1);` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this syntax:

```
(*funArr[0].fun)();
```

Also, don't cast, your function types differ and things will crash, try this:

```
typedef int (*coolFunct) (unsigned int);

struct fun_desc {
  char *name;
  coolFunct fun;
};

(*funArr[0].fun)(1);
```

EDIT: If you actually *want* to cast, the syntax for calling is:

```
((coolFunct)funArr[0].fun)(1);
```

Comment: Wrong. a) You don't need to dereference before you call, and b) you need to cast back to the appropriate signature (the function is `int (*)(unsigned)` but you're calling it using a `void (*)()` which is UB)

Comment: is there a way to implement this with a void * pointer ? trying to get the returned int value of the function i get : error: void value not ignored as it ought to be

Comment: The cast is legal. The standard mandates that casting a function pointer type to another function pointer type and back again yields the original function. It is a common technique to create a "generic" function pointer type, cast all functions to this type for storage and then cast them back to the appropriate type to call them.

Comment: @james t - It is unsafe by the C standard to store function pointers in a `void *` pointer (or any other object pointer) type. It's part of the POSIX standard and probably works on Windows, if that's "good enough" for you. But your method should be working. If it's not, the code in your program must be different from the sample code you've posted.

Comment: a) habit, due to member fp's, and works. But yes, cleaner without the deref. b) The struct var signature *is* `void(*)()` - whether his function actually is using the typedef or the type from the struct remains to be seen.

Comment: @Erik - The OP says his functions are of type `int (*)(unsigned int)`, so to call a function with that signature stored in a function pointer of another signature, you need to cast it back to the original signature.

Comment: @Chris: Yes, just reread and saw that he actually wants to cast - it's not just a mistake on his side using the different signatures.

Comment: thanks everyone, casting works, although i have some gcc warnings, but that's because of the void (*) pointers, thanks for the tips, but i'm the use of void (*) is intentional (requirement for a lab)

Answer (score 2):

You need to cast the function pointers when you store them in the struct.  Your compiler is supposed to give you a diagnostic for this.  It's hard to see how it could be the source of your problems though.

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef int (*coolFunct) (unsigned int);
typedef void (*whackFunct)();

int f1(unsigned i) { puts("f1"); return 1; }
int f2(unsigned i) { puts("f2"); return 2; }

struct fun_desc {
  char *name;
  void (*fun)();
};

struct fun_desc funArr[]={{"f1", (whackFunct)&f1}, {"f2", (whackFunct)&f2}};

int main()
{
    printf("function returned %d\n", ((coolFunct)funArr[0].fun)(1));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: that took care of the warnings :-)